# OpenGL Stereo: alternating between left and right textures

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, stereo-3d

I am working with openGL quad buffer to  render stereo 3D images (and I am very new to openGL).

I came across a question on how to define the output texture for each back buffer, which I supose is done in the fragment buffer by defining the output color  (corresponding to a specified texture).

This is the code I am using  for the shader sources:

```
// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec3 color;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec3 Color;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    " Color = color;"
    " Texcoord = texcoord;"
    " gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
  "}"; // Vertex buffer source
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec3 Color;"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "uniform sampler2D texRight;"
    "uniform sampler2D texLeft;"
    "void main() {"
    " outColor = texture(texRight, Texcoord);"
    " outColor = texture(texLeft, Texcoord);"
  "}"; // Fragment buffer source
```

This is the code I am using to fill the back buffers, that I use in the display function for the freeglut context window.

```
 // Clear Buffers
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f);

    cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)d_glpointer, pbo);

    cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)d_glpointer, pbo_Right);
    //...

    // Unmap buffer object
    cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo);
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesID[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL); // NULL specifies that the image is in memory

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texLeft"), 1);

    // Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


    // Unmap buffer object
    cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo_Right);
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo_Right);

   // Draw Back Buffers
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesID[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL); // NULL specifies that the image is in memory

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texRight"), 0);

    // Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // Swap buffers
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

By using this code I am able to see only the last outcolor defined, but I was not able to figure out a functional way to choose between the outColor definition depending on the buffer I am using.

I am using Cuda to put the images in memory, but the problem doesn't seem related to this mapping, since I am always able to see the image associated with texture defined last in the shader's outcolor.

I'll appreciate some help on figuring this out.

Edit 1:
I added a counter to the shader that verifies if the frame count (texCount) is even or odd. Although, I have no output image now.

```
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D texRight;
uniform sampler2D texLeft;
uniform int texCount=1;

void main() {
if (texCount%2){ // if texCount division by two is exact then this is false
    outColor = texture(texLeft, Texcoord);
}else{
    outColor = texture(texRight, Texcoord);
}
texCount++;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to display two textures alternatively, ie texture 0 on even frames, and texture 1 on odd frames? (or `texLeft` and `texRight`).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly What I want to do. Although only texture 1 is being displayed ("texleft").

Comment: Would it be possible to add a uniform in the fragment shader indicating which texture must be used (0 or 1), and update that value each frame (something like `frame_counter % 2`)?

Comment: I've added a flag (GLuint texCount) that changes from 0 to 1 after glBindBuffer, and my fragment shader now looks as follows, but now I have no image being displayed:#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D texRight;
uniform sampler2D texLeft;

void main() {
if (texCount==1){
    outColor = texture(texLeft, Texcoord);
}else if (texCount==0){
    outColor = texture(texRight, Texcoord);
}
}

Comment: Well, it is not surprising that nothing is output. Your new shader uses undefined variables, thus it will not compile. By the way, you should edit your question to include any changes rather than put them in impossible to read comments.

Comment: I was wondering if I defined the counter as global variable outside the shader, it won't do the trick. Has you noticed it does not do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were outputing to different backbuffers in the same frame render. I made an answer based on that. Hopefully it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work.

The new fragment shader:

```
#version 150 core in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D texIndex;
void main() {
    outColor = texture(texIndex, Texcoord); 
}
```

Then replace `”texLeft”` and `”texRight”` in your code by `”texIndex”`.

Note that you shouldn't have to upload the textures at each frame if they are static. Ideally, you would put all the commands that need to be executed only once in a setup function, which you would execute only when the OS notify a window reshape.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. In this particular case I am rendering several images in a directory into the texture, for that reason I need to do the texture upload at each frame.

Comment: You'll probably want to assign a value to `outColor`, otherwise this shader will not do much.